# How can i send bulk emails using php

Tags: email, phpmailer, bulk, bulk-email

I want send bulk emails on one action but user shouldn't wait upto end of email sending process. after clicking the button user should get success message and process should continue in back-end, but i don't want to use any third party service. please tell me any possible way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked in a very general way, so this is a very generalised answer. There are several ways you can do this. The easiest is to an existing mailing app, the most obvious of which is [PHPList](http://www.phplist.com), though there is also [PHPMailer-ML](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=phpmailerml).

The key concept is that you need to separate the sending from the command to send, and that the actual sending is not done from a web page script. You can do this many ways, for example insert a value saying 'send this email to these people' in a database, then have a separate process (either a daemon or cron job) poll the database for mailing jobs and send them asynchronously. You can do something similar with a queue like [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/).